# TypeError when writing large dataset to Excel using Python xlwings

Tags: python, pandas, excel, datetime, xlwings

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2). df1 is imported from a csv and is about 500 records and I can use the `.tables['table_name'].update()` method perfectly fine.

df2 is a concatenation data imported from an excel sheet and df1. It is a large dataset (>90K records). When I try to write df2 to the excel work, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Objects of type 'datetime.time' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT
```

Both dataframes have a [datetime64[ns]' column

My code looks like this:

```
report = xw.Book(workbook_path)
append_sheet = report.sheets['Sheet to append to']


df2 = xlsheet_data_df.concat(df1)

append_sheet.tables[0].update(df2, index=False)
```

The part I'm having trouble understanding is why my code isn't working all of a sudden. I did have the same error yesterday, but I just ran the script again and it worked, but I get nothing now.

I've looked to other questions people have posted, but no luck.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of `df2`, for example the output of `df2.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: I have it on my work computer. Could you expand on what you'd about it you want to know?

Comment: *this is my personal

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem you simply can solve it by formatting the datetime column into a string by using the following code:

```
import datetime  

df[columns_to_replace] = df[columns_to_replace].applymap(lambda x: str(x) if isinstance(x, datetimetime) else x)
```

Comment: I only need to replace the one column, and a Series object does not have an .applymap() method

When done on the entire DateFrame this results in: NameError: name 'datetimetime' is not defined

Comment: I tried 'datetime.datetime' instead of 'datetimetime' within the isinstance() function. Gets rid of the NameError, but when writing to excel it still results in the TypeError described above